# What is the difference between "suspicious" and "suspected"?

Tags: meaning

For example,

> suspected malfunction

Is it ok to interpret "suspected" as "suspicious"?

Comment: Would you tell us what's ambiguous between the two for you? Would you add your takes on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't say these two words mean the same thing, and they are certainly not interchangeable.

"Suspected malfunction" means that you believe there is a malfunction, but you haven't checked it in enough detail to be sure. As in: There is no proof yet.

"Suspicious" is someone or something that you do not trust. So, a website or a person can be suspicious, but you wouldn't normally describe a malfunction in this way.

Two example definitions from Macmillan Dictionary:

1. a **suspected** criminal is one who the courts have not yet proved guilty.
2. **suspicious:** a feeling that someone or something cannot be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

Those two words are similar, but they can't be interchanged.

'Suspected' describes a fact about something. It is more objective and concrete than 'suspicion' in that a person or thing is either suspected or not. In the case of a person it doesn't mean they have actually done the thing, but it means that they have been accused of that specific thing and we can all verify that they have been accused. In your example, the problem is suspected to be a malfunction. We don't know what the problem is but we agree that a malfunction is thought to be the problem.

> He is suspected of lying.
>   That dog is suspected of biting my friend.
>   The problem suspected to be due to a malfunction.

'Suspicious' is a much more subjective word. It expresses an opinion that might or might not be based in facts and can't be proven. One person can think something or someone is suspicious, but another person can easily disagree.

> The way he talks makes him suspicious.
>   The lack of detail in that explanation is suspicious.

If we say 'it is suspicious malfunction' it means we know there is a malfunction, and we think that it indicates that something is not as we think it is. There shouldn't be a malfunction and because there is one we don't trust the situation.